# PHPSpreadsheet me cambia numeros al ponerlos en un excel

Tags: php, mysql, firebase, phpspreadsheet

Resulta que estoy trayendo en PHP unos valores de mi base de datos, los cuales están guardados como String, ya que los clientes pueden poner caracteres alfanuméricos, el caso es que uno de los clientes se dio cuenta de que su dato estaba llegando incorrecto en el excel, mientras que en la pagina salia bien, y yo tampoco entiendo porque en el excel los valores se "redondean" tan extremo, un ejemplo: tengo este valor, "232740538390866", pero en el Excel me queda así, "232740538390870" unos son menos sutiles de valores que terminan en 1, y los cambia a 0, ya probé cambiando el formato de la celda, pero no es posible, así mismo el idioma del archivo con "setlocale" pero nada, y no entiendo porque se cambia así un dato que en teoria es un texto, no un numero, gracias.

Código donde obtengo la variable:

```
             if( array_key_exists('datossolicita', $valor) ){
            
                $datossolicita = $valor['datossolicita'];
                $nombresolicita = $datossolicita['nombre'];
                
                if( array_key_exists('valor', $datossolicita) ){
                    $copago = $datossolicita['valor'];
                }

                if( array_key_exists('autorizacion', $datossolicita) ){
                    $numeroautorizacion = $datossolicita['autorizacion'];
                }

            }
```

Código donde pongo el campo en el excel:

```
                $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ...
                ->setCellValue("X".$i, $numeroautorizacion)
                $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('X'.$i. ':X'.$i)- 
                >getNumberFormat()- 
             >setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

PD: Coloco la celda como formato numero, para que salga el dato completo y no acortado, que ya probé removiendo eso y sigue igual

Comment: Encontré que la única forma en que el Excel no me modifique los datos, era colocando "-" al inicio y al final, de esta forma: "->setCellValue("X".$i, " ".$numeroautorizacion." ")" Pero pues no es lo ideal.

Comment: Hola Diego, ¿en que formato guardas el archivo? En `xls, xlsx`, etc. ¿Podrías compartir el link a un archivo donde se pueda ver/reproducir este comportamiento?

Comment: [Según la doc](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/) las cadenas numéricas son convertidas al tipo de dato más adecuado, de modo que las cadenas con sólo números son convertidas a números. Puede que al ser de gran valor una parte de ellos se pierda, o que la librería tenga un bug. Allí mismo explican que puedes usar [data binders personalizados](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/#using-value-binders-to-facilitate-data-entry), por ejemplo para evitar que las cadenas se conviertan a número.